# How to set parameters within '' in EJB query

Tags: ejbql

In EJB query, it's recommended to use setParameters() instead of concatenating string parameters in order to avoid SQL injection attack.

My question is: how to set parameters within '' in SQL update statements with 'SET':

```
String basicQuery = "update some table set somecolumn = ':para'";
Query query = em.createQuery(basicQuery);
query.setParameters("para", someString);
```

The runtime complains that it cannot locate parameter "para". Any workaround is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes around `:para`.

Comment: This answer would have been just |_| that much better if you had said, "The quotes are not needed when using named parameters and are interfering with the syntax" as opposed to just saying "remove them".

Comment: No it will not - you're not writing SQL. You're writing EJBQL (or JPAQL) which is an abstraction. `:para` is the syntax for a named parameter (named "para") and `setParameter` takes the name and value, and the JPA implementation will sanitize the input, add quotes, etc.